# No package nodejs available. Error: Nothing to do. Rails App On Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ruby-on-rails-6

I've been using my Rails 6 app on Elastic Beanstalk for more than 6 months with no issue. Suddenly yesterday after deploying some changes the build started to fail due to it not being able to install `NodeJs`, which is not related to the changes I'd deployed earlier.

I have `01_download_nodejs` and `02_install_nodejs` commands for eb configs and they haven't been changed since I've setup the app for the first time around 6 months ago.

In `cfn-init.log` file it shows the following:

```
2021-10-02 08:46:19,017 [INFO] Command 01_download_nodejs succeeded
2021-10-02 08:46:23,515 [ERROR] Command 02_install_nodejs (yum -y install nodejs) failed
2021-10-02 08:46:23,516 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of prebuild_2_sst_app: 
Command 02_install_nodejs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
  CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
  self._config.commands)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
  raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 02_install_nodejs failed
2021-10-02 08:46:23,516 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2021-10-02 08:46:23,516 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 
02_install_nodejs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 176, in <module>
  worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 135, in build
  Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 561, in build
  self.run_config(config, worklog)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
  CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
  self._config.commands)
File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
  raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 02_install_nodejs failed
```

In `cfn-init-cmd.log` file it shows the following:

```
2021-10-02 08:46:18,976 P22197 [INFO] Command 01_download_nodejs
2021-10-02 08:46:19,017 P22197 [INFO] Completed successfully.
2021-10-02 08:46:19,017 P22197 [INFO] 
============================================================
2021-10-02 08:46:19,017 P22197 [INFO] Command 02_install_nodejs
2021-10-02 08:46:23,514 P22197 [INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
2021-10-02 08:46:23,515 P22197 [INFO]   Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
2021-10-02 08:46:23,515 P22197 [INFO]   No package nodejs available.
2021-10-02 08:46:23,515 P22197 [INFO]   Error: Nothing to do
2021-10-02 08:46:23,515 P22197 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
2021-10-02 08:46:23,515 P22197 [ERROR] Exited with error code 1
```

`01_download_nodejs:`

`command: "curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | sudo -E bash -"`

`02_install_nodejs:`

`command: "yum -y install nodejs"`

Elastic Beanstalk Platform Version: 3.3.5

Comment: Sadly your question is not clear. What EB platform version are you using exactly?

Comment: The version is 3.3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue you are probably having is due to expired SSL certificates, as described here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-expired-certificate/

You can solve this with file in .ebextensions that installs the latest certificate. E.g, for Amazon Linux 1:

```
commands:
  00_ssl_certs:
    command: yum -y install https://cdn.amazonlinux.com/patch/ca-certificates-update-2021-09-30/ca-certificates-2018.2.22-65.1.24.amzn1.noarch.rpm
```